# Deleted Kali identifier but still it shows in bios

Tags: kali-linux, uninstall

Previously I had installed Kali Linux but few days later I deleted it. The way I did it (1) was to first delete the partition then using diskpart and rd. Still it was showing on my BIOS. So (2) I deleted the identifier. But recently it popped up again on my BIOS. In firmware except the windows boot manager there are 5 other firmwares. Their descriptions are: windows boot manager, Debian, EFI USB, EFI DVD/CDROM, EFI Network. No matter how many times I delete Kali identifier it still shows in the BIOS. But it doesn't show in the firmware list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete unused EFI entries with `efibootmgr`.

1. List the currently present entries by running `efibootmgr`
   The output should look as following:

```
$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0010,0011,0012,0013,0017,0018,0019,001A,001B,001C,001D,001E
Boot0000* Fedora
Boot0010 Setup
Boot0011 Boot Menu
Boot0012 Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0013 Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0014 Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0015 Rescue and Recovery
Boot0016 MEBx Hot Key
Boot0017* USB CD
Boot0018* USB FDD
```

2. Make note of the "bootnum", e.g. Boot0000
3. Delete the unwanted entry, e.g. Fedora by running `efibootmgr --delete-bootnum --bootnum 0000`